# When I PATCH a Boolean field, the update is reflected in the database but not the JSON output, why? (Django Rest Framework Serializer)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Assuming I have to override the update method in DRF's ModelSerializer - whenever I run PATCH to update a Boolean field from False to True, it will not be reflected in the JSON output. But when I check it is reflected in the SQLite database. Then, I run PATCH or GET to query data again, only then will the change show in the JSON output. Why does this happen and is there a way for the change to be reflected in the JSON body output immediately?

The code below shows a stripped down version of my JobSerializer class.

```
class JobSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = (
            'slug',
            'student',
            'service',
            'time_slots',
            'tutor_accept',
        )

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.tutor_accept = validated_data.get('tutor_accept', instance.tutor_accept)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

And here is my Job model.

```
class Job(MyModel):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='jobs', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, related_name='jobs', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    time_slots = models.ManyToManyField(Schedule)
    tutor_accept = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Here is my JobDetail view:

```
class JobDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Job.objects.all()
    serializer_class = JobSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    lookup_field = 'slug'
```

MyModel base class

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    slug = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Comment: can you add a view where you use the serializer?

Comment: The culprit is your view. Can you show that? Are you using mixins?

Comment: I have added my view. Thank you for the comments!

Comment: @cal what is `MyModel` ? Can you add that too ?

Comment: @cal As it is now, it should work as you'd expect. But you mentioned `stripped down version of Jobserializer`. Can you add full implementation of your serializer

Comment: added MyModel!!

Comment: After some hours of debugging it seems I have found the issue. Accessing self in the update() function of the serializer leads to some problems so we should avoid that. Thanks anyway Martin

Comment: well. you should ave posted full implementation of your serializer. like it was in your question, it should have worked as expected